# Limit regex expression by character in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I get the following pattern `(\s\w+)` I need matches every words in my string with a space.

For example

When i have this string

```
many word in the textarea must be happy
```

I get

```
 many     
 word    
 in    
 the    
 textarea    
 must    
 be    
 happy
```

It is correct, but when i have another character, for example

```
many word in the textarea , must be happy
```

I get

```
 many     
 word    
 in    
 the    
 textarea    
 must    
 be    
 happy
```

But  `must be happy` should be ignored, because i want it to break when another character is in the string

Edit:

Example 2

```
all cats  { in } the world are nice
```

Should be return

```
all
cats
```

Because `{` is another separator for me

Example 3

```
My 3 cats are ... funny
```

Should be return

```
My
3
cats
are
```

Because `3` is alphanumeric and `.` is separator for me

What can I do?

Comment: you can use anchor symbols.  `^` means the beginning of input and `$` means the end of input.

Comment: it'll be easiest if you run 2 regex

Comment: you could split the string before processing by ','

Comment: @SamIam when i add `^` and `$` `^(\s\w+)$` the pattern not found any word

Comment: @thumbmunkeys but i need split for any no-alphanumeric character, there is no way to do this with regular expression?

Comment: @jasilva I didn't tell you to run `^(\s\w+)$`.  That regex won't match anything because you have more than 1 word in your input.  I told you what `^` and `$` meant, and I told you that they might be helpful.

Comment: so if you wanted to select everything up to the comma, you'd do `^.*,`

Comment: @SamIam I think I've got it. Inspired in `^.*,` i test `^(\s\w+)+` or `^(\s+\w+)+` for many whitespaces. It seems to work well in http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: Why not just use `text.Split(',')[0].Split();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to use the `\G` anchors that matches the positions at the start of the string or after the last match. so you can do it with this pattern:

```
@"(?<=\G\s*)\w+"
```

Comment: We have a winner!,  oh tkxs `^(\s\w+)+` match the correct lenght of string in my conditions, but return like 1 string `bla bla bla` but your pattern return 'bla' 'bla' 'bla'

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\w\s\n].*$|(\w+\s+)
```

Try this.Grab the captures or matches.See demo.Set flag `m` for multiline mode.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/12

Comment: I do not vote, but I think this was because the example for PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think Sam I Am's comment is correct: you'll require two regular expressions.

1. Capture the text up to a non-word character.
2. Capture all the words with a space on one side.

Here's the corresponding code:

1. `"^(\\w+\\s+)+"`
2. `"(\\w+\\s+)"`

You can combine these two to capture just the individual words pretty easily - like so

`"^(\\w+\\s+)+"`

Here's a complete piece of code demonstrating the pattern:

```
string input = "many word in the textarea , must be happy";

string pattern = "^(\\w+\\s+)+";

Match match = Regex.Match(input , pattern);

// Never returns a NullReferenceException because of GroupsCollection array indexer - check it out!
foreach(Capture capture in match.Groups[1].Captures)
{
    Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
}
```

**EDIT**

Check out Casimir et Hippolyte for a really clean answer.

Answer (score -1):

All in one regex :-) Result is in `list`

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^((\w+)\s*)+([^\w\s]|$).*");

Match m = regex.Match(inputString);
if(m.Success)
{
    List<string> list = 
        m.Groups[2].Captures.Cast<Capture>().
        Select(c=>c.Value).ToList();
}
```